# Sharing a bool across threads, any pittraps to the naive approach?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need a simple bool to notify a long running process to abord as part of a loop that looks like this:

```
bool Abort = false;
void MyLongRunningMethod()
{
while(true)
{
    // loop code goes here, takes 2 hours ish to run
    if(Abort)
       break;
}
}
```

I know how to write this properly, however i'm wondering, are there any risks if i leave it as is instead? Or is the only risk (which is a non issue in my case) that the loop could run an additional time (reading the bool at the same time as it's getting written).

Am i missing any weird edge cases or is this actually perfectly ok if i'm fine with the following statement : "the method should break when abort is true, but may run an additional time after it with no side effects" ? Or am i missing something that could completely break the world there?

Comment: What makes you think the loop can only run one additional time? What argument that it can run one time doesn't also argue that it might run two times, or two million times?

Comment: I'm really only interested in practical situation here and even outside of my case, how could i run 2 million times? Can you think of an operation that take 1/2 000 000 of the time it takes to write to a bool? But in my case it's even more clear cut, the content of the while loop takes a couple hours to run, so yea i'm pretty sure if something is setting the bool to true "right" when i'm reading it, it'll be done setting it to true 2 hours later :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with how long it takes to write a bool. It has to do with whether the compiler optimizes away the read from memory inside the loop. If the compiler can prove that nothing inside the loop can modify `Abort`, it can move the read from `Abort` to outside the loop. This is what compilers do all the time when they, for example, keep a loop index in a register.

Comment: Well i guess that's exactly what i'm looking for then, nothing makes me think it will run one additional time, it's exactly why i'm asking here, i have no clue what risks to happen, could you clarify what you mean? Why would the compiler optimize that out? (doesn't seem to make any functional sense to optimise a read from a class variable?)

Comment: Think about a basic for loop. You think the compiler reads the loop index from memory, and writes it to memory, each time in the loop? Of course not. Where possible, the compiler optimizes away those reads and writes by keeping the loop index in a register. Rather than making compilers unable to do optimizations by having to assume that another thread could change a variable at any time, sensible languages require code that has cross-thread dependencies to use synchronization mechanisms such as the `volatile` keyword, mutexes, thread-safe atomic types, and so on.

Comment: FYI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JohnnyMopp As i said i know how to cancel perfectly fine, i'm just wondering, in my specific use case (which is, i don't care if it runs additional times for a while), what happens if i don't. My question is 100% not "how do i write a cancelable action", i know how to do that "the right way (tm)" :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well in a basic for loop you're not usually using outside of the method data in the loop, also i don't get where you're getting to with this, a mutex wouldn't change anything if the variable was cached by the compiler for example, while it would lock the access, you'd still "read the cache" by your logic. Now i do see where you're coming from with volatile however. Is there any documentation about when something is likely to be or not be optimized?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau "*a mutex wouldn't change anything if the variable was cached by the compiler for example*" Yes, it would. The compiler will do whatever it has to do to make the mutex work, otherwise the compiler doesn't support mutexes. Since the C# language has mutexes, C# compilers have to support them.

Comment: The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.
The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the `bool` here should be marked [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) to create a memory barrier / prevent some caching from giving you a false negative. Second, `CancellationTokenSource` is a great alternative to this:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();

void MyLongRunningMethod()
{
    while (!_cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // loop code goes here, takes 2 hours ish to run
    }
}
```

Then to stop the loop:

```
_cancel.Cancel();
```

If you wish to leave it the way you originally wrote it, do `while (!Abort)` instead of `while (true)`

Comment: while(!Abort), surely.

Comment: The `while (true)` style allows the abort to happen in the middle of the body, and also makes it easy to access from within a `lock` statement. While `volatile` will work, `lock` is the more general solution.

Comment: @Gabe - why `lock` on a bool type? The changing of it is atomic in that there is no risk of a null reference. Forcing a single thread at a time to read it is not as efficient as using `volatile` and allowing all threads to read it as they please.

Comment: @DavidHaney: It may work in this case, but in general this optimization is fraught with danger. See http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/ for how it can fail unexpectedly.

Comment: @Gabe while I appreciate the article posted, the issue that Eric seems to strike on is not with volatility but with atomicity of multiple operations. When you need to atomically set > 1 value, yes, a lock is absolutely needed. Setting a single volatile bool, however, seems fairly harmless to me since a previous arbitrary read "back in time" is OK here as well.

Comment: @Gabe as for the `while (true)` allowing the abort to happen in the middle of the body, there's no reason I cannot check `_cancel.IsCancellationRequested` in multiple locations throughout the body and break the loop accordingly.

Comment: Generally, if an atomic or volatile type provides exactly what you need, it's the best solution. Otherwise, use a lock.